# How do I set properties in a class with a parameterless constructor on instantiation in one statement?

Tags: c#, syntax, constructor, instantiation

I'm 103% sure this is possible and that I've seen it, but I can't remember where or what the syntax was.

I thought it was something like `var obj = new Thing({Id=3, Name="The Thing"});` but that's not working.

If I'm crazy, just tell me so. I really don't think I am...or maybe I'm just too crazy to realize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work

```
var obj = new Thing{Id=3, Name="The Thing"};
```

Answer (score 2):

You need like:

```
var obj = new Thing{Id=3, Name="The Thing"};
```

The name of this is `Object Initializer`.

Comment: I LITERALLY just figured it out about 10 seconds before you posted this. It never fails. The quickest way for me to remember something is to post a question on SO. Thanks, man.

Comment: No parenthesis needed.

Comment: Do they hurt anything, @mao47? I actually like that syntax a little better if it doesn't.

Comment: @Yatrix: I suppose not but I find them a bit clutter-y